# Datatype to store integers and arithmetic operators?

Tags: c, rpn

Is there any way that I can take input of numbers from users and also any arithmetic operator on a user choice when user wants to enter. I am basically trying to make a sort of calculator in which user will first enter numbers and in last the operators to be applicable on it. But there is no any fix limit that user will first input how many numbers. Its user wish. And my program should guess by itself that is it a character input or a integer input. Is it possible ??

Comment: `user will first enter numbers and in last the operators to be applicable on it` - So... you want to handle postfix expressions?

Comment: How do you envision associating the operators with the numbers? For the input "1 2 3 + -", does that mean (1 + 2) - 3 or 1 + (2 - 3)?

Answer (score 1):

It's Just an overview to proceed in simple arithmetic kind of programming problem.

Take input as character and store in the char array buffer.
And then using `strtol` you can convert that to `long int`.

[For more about strtol()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)

Also take operators as a character array where character at each index will represent operator.

Apply `switch - case` and based on that cases(which will be operators `+` , `-` and so on ) perform you operations.

Other way is to convert `infix arithmetic notations` to `postfix notations` and use `stacks` for that and simply solve .In this case there won't be problem with the operator precedence since you have already applied that logic to store operators into stack , just pop one by one and perform operation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that user can only enter one of the follwing operation format:

```
x + y
x * y
x - y
x / y
```

Here after how you can do it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main () {
    int x, y;
    char op;

    printf ("Enter your Expression The Format should be One of the following:\nx + y\nx - y\nx * y\nx / y\n");
    if (scanf("%d %c %d",&x,&op,&y)<3) {
        printf("Wrong Expression\n");
        return 0;
    }
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            printf("%d + %d = %d\n",x,y,x+y );
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("%d - %d = %d\n",x,y,x-y );
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n",x,y,x*y );
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("%d / %d = %d\n",x,y,x/y );
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid operator %c\n",op);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An integer should be started with 0~9 or minus sign.

An operator should be one character minus sign or other than 0~9 character.

Get your inputs as string, make judge if it's an operator or integer, then use atoi to convert string to integer.

If you are capable of writing a calculator, that should be simple task to you.

Answer (score 0):

My Advice would be to build an OPP(object precedence parser) to operate on a string input by user. 
When you take input as a string the user has the authority to enter the entire algebric equation along with the arithmetic operators, because they are considered as chars only. Then you can get it either converted to a char array perform OPP operations on it. 
http://code.google.com/p/expressionparser/

Or what you can do is a step by step input like number,then operator then number :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really list many details or any examples of how you want to handle this, so I can't give you better advice. Since you don't know the order, or amount of input (digits/characters) it's advisable to take it as a string:

```
char *expression_buf = NULL;
scanf("%m[^\n]", expression_buf); // grab any number of characters/digits with spaces
//do some postfix stuff
free(expression_buf);
```

Then you can figure out what is a digit and what's not by:

```
#include <ctype.h>
isdigit(expression_buf[index])
```

That's pretty much all the tools you'd need. Then pop off the digits/operators and apply them in order. Placing them on stacks will help so you can pop them back off in the right order.